# Texworks interprets double quotes as two single ones, more specifically \"{} as \'{'}

Tags: accents, ubuntu, texworks

I have an funny, yet annoying, issue that I only recently discovered as I started writing in Dutch. (As such I can not trace when the issue started)

My Texworks (ubuntu Gnome 14.04 ) interprets \"{} as \'{'}. I therefore loose access to an important accent. The syntax coloring confirms this: in \" only the back-slash and the first single quote turns blue, the second remains black. I exclusively compile with pdfLaTeX, so I dont know if the problem would exist with other compilers in texworks.

If I compile my code with texmaker (which I usually not use), I do not have this issue, so I am pretty sure it is related to texworks alone, it also happens in all my documents, so I am pretty sure its not a package. That leaves a setting somewhere, but I do not have a clue which one that could be.

Any idea how to fix this? At this point an alternative method to compile an umlaut/trema, if it even exists, would also be acceptable (though of course not preferred).

Comment: Hi and welcome, texworks uses utf8 by default, you can simply input your characters as Ä, ü, ß, á, and others. All you need is `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Very annoying bug indeed! I tried changing the preferences about “Smart Quotes”, but the program doesn't seem to obey them and change `"` into two apostrophes nonetheless. :( For what it's worth, it doesn't happen on Mac OS X.

Comment: @egreg Did you close and restart TeXworks?

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, I did.

Comment: @Johannes_B, thanks, that is a good intermediate solution, which I will start to use for now, pending a solution to the actual problem...

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. But I could deactivate the smart quotes: For new document one should change the settings in the general options. For *existing* documents one must adapt the settings in the Format menu.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, that does it for me, I overlooked the format menu. Thanks! I

Answer (score 8):

After @UlrikeFischers comment. The solution for me was that I had to change the (default?) smart quote setting to `none' in **both** the preferences menu for Texworks in general **and** in the the format menu for existing documents.